# laravel named route helper doesn't generate url with parametes.

Tags: string, laravel, parameters, named-routing

The laravel named route it makes query strings I don't want.

From the docs:

> **LARAVEL 5.6**
>
> accessing named route in LARAVEL generates URL with query string if i
>   pass parameters to the second argument of the route() helper witch i
>   don't want.  i want URL parameters get passed.

My code:

```
Route::get('/posts/count', 'PostController@index');

route(posts.index, [count => 3]) // /posts?3  
// i don't want this but i get it

route(posts.index, [count => 3]) // /posts/3  
// i want this but i don't get it
```

Comment: can you elaborate??

Comment: you would need there to actually be a parameter that needs replacing in the URI anything else is added as a query param

Comment: Are you using `resource` as  `Route::resource(/posts', 'PostController');` ?

Comment: you don't have `named route` here

Answer (score 3):

you should define route variable with {}

like this

```
Route::get('/posts/{count}', 'PostController@index');
```